# How decompose NSPredicate into components?

Tags: iphone, core-data, nspredicate

Is there any common way to decompose an expression created by [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat] to objects NSComprasionPredicate, NSExpression and other?

For below example need to disassemble into components.

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(0 != SUBQUERY(collection, $x, $x.name == "Name").@Count)"];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`+[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:]` is actually the front-end for a rather sophisticated parser.  If you introspect the resulting `NSPredicate`, you'll find that it's not actually an `NSPredicate`, but either an `NSComparisonPredicate` or an `NSCompoundPredicate`.

Both of those types of predicates have lots of handy methods for convenient introspection.

In other words: `NSPredicate` is actually an "abstract" class.  You'll usually only ever deal with comparison or compound predicates.  There are other kinds, such as `NSBlockPredicate`, but they're all undocumented.

Comment: Sounds like a class cluster to me, like NSString and the Cocoa collections.

Comment: I can imagine how to create predicate with predicateWithFormat. But I can not create predicate (in my question) using a set of objects such as NSExpression, NSComparisonPredicate, NSCompoundPredicate.